# What is the correct type of a 'set' function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function in TypeScript like this:

```
set parameter(value: string) {
  this._paremeter = value;
}
```

This works fine. I thought for the sake of completeness: Let's add the correct type that says this function doesn't retun anything. However, none is working:

```
set parameter(vale: string): void {}
set parameter(vale: string): never {}
```

I also tried these, just to make sure. But of course any of these won't work either:

```
set parameter(vale: string): undefined {}
set parameter(vale: string): null {}
```

Is there a correct type or should a `set`-function simply have no type at all?

Comment: set method can't have a return type annotation.

Comment: Note the error message returned for your examples: '*A 'set' accessor cannot have a return type annotation.*'

Comment: here's thread https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9370

Comment: @JoeClay Oh boy, I misread the error message. I thought it says, that the used type is not allowed.

Comment: @DPro Thanks for that link. I was also looking for something from the official docs etc.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I understand that a set function should not return a value, but if you want your code to be full strict, it sucks that you can't set it to never/void

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setters do not support specifying a return type.

[From the (now deprecated) language specification:](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/02d5b23aae1b43839f5f82800e993564dcecce4d/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#a2-expressions)

> *SetAccessor:*
>  `set` *PropertyName* `(` *BindingIdentifierOrPattern TypeAnnotation (optional)* `)` `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something from the docs, but I couldn't find it. That makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors)

> TypeScript supports getters/setters as a way of intercepting accesses to a member of an 
>   object. This gives you a way of having finer-grained control over how
>   a member is accessed on each object.

And there is an example of a **set**

```
set fullName(newName: string) {
        if (newName && newName.length > fullNameMaxLength) {
            throw new Error("fullName has a max length of " + fullNameMaxLength);
        }

        this._fullName = newName;
    }
```

In concluision, a set method cannot return a type so, your first approach is the right one.

```
set parameter(value: string) {
  this._paremeter = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'set' accessor cannot have a return type annotation in Typescript language.

If you have tslint activated, it will show error ts(1095)